# Prove that the variance of the MLE of $f(x\mid\theta)=θx^{θ−1}$ tends to $0$ for large $n$

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I am given that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are randomly sampled from the following distribution:
$f(x\mid\theta)=\theta x^{\theta−1}$, $0<x<1,$ $0<θ<∞.$

I need to show that the variance of the MLE of $θ$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity.

I know that the MLE of $θ$ is $\hat{\theta} =\frac{-1}{(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i}$.

I am stuck on finding the variance of the MLE, however.

I've been thinking about solving $E(X^2) = \int x^2f(x)\,dx$ and $E(X) = \int xf(x) \, dx$ with the MLE as the argument, and rearranging to solve for $\operatorname{var}(\widehat{\theta})$, but I'm not sure of what $f(x)$ would look like using the MLE. It's a really hairy looking integral.

For instance,  $E(\,\widehat{\theta^2}\,) = \int \left( \frac{-1}{(1/n) \sum_{i=1}^n\log X_i} \right)^2 \theta x^{\theta−1}\,dx$ would require that I uniformly replace $\theta$ with the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ ?
Does this look right? Am I on the right/wrong track?

Comment: Do you know about asymptotic normality of the MLE?

Comment: If $X\sim f(x|\theta)$ it's pretty easy to show that $-\ln(X)\sim \exp(\theta)$ which makes $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n-\ln(X_j)\sim \text{Erlang}(n,n\theta)$$

Comment: Set $Y=-\ln(X)$ and compute $F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)$ for $y\in (0,\infty)$

Comment: @rubikscube09 I just tried using it for the first time could you please check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

If $X \sim f(x|\theta)$ it's pretty easy to show that $-\ln(X)\sim \exp(\theta)$ which makes $$\frac{1}{\hat{\theta}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n-\ln(X_j)\sim \text{Erlang}(n,n\theta)$$ From the law of the unconscious statistician,  $$\mathbb{E}\Big(\hat{\theta}\Big)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\cdot \frac{(n\theta)^nt^{n-1}e^{-n\theta t}}{(n-1)!}dt=\frac{n\theta}{n-1}$$

$$\mathbb{E}\Big(\hat{\theta}^2\Big)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\cdot \frac{(n\theta)^nt^{n-1}e^{-n\theta t}}{(n-1)!}dt=\frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$$ So finally, $$\mathbb{V}\Big(\hat{\theta}\Big)=\mathbb{E}\Big(\hat{\theta}^2\Big)-\Big(\mathbb{E}\big(\hat{\theta}\big)\Big)^2=\frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}-\Bigg(\frac{n\theta}{n-1}\Bigg)^2$$ which tends to $0$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$.

Comment: It depends on how you're parameterizing the exponential distribution. To be clear, the pdf of $Y=-\ln(X)$ is $f_{Y}(y)=\theta e^{-\theta y}$ for $y>0$. Some sources refer to this as an $\exp(\theta)$ distribution while others refer to this as $\exp(1/\theta)$

Comment: To see this, notice for $y\in (0,\infty)$ that $$P(Y \leq y)=P(X \geq e^{-y})=\int_{e^{-y}}^1\theta x^{\theta-1}dx=1-e^{-\theta y}$$ Now differentiate to get $f_{Y}(y).$